# What fan could I use to extract hot air from an oven?

Tags: amplifier, protection, fan, heatsink

I am making an reflow oven. I've decided to use the picoReflow to do the job and monitor it.

The oven is originally a lab oven, and it doesn't cool quickly at all. It has a vent at the top which I'd like to use for cooling, but just opening it is insufficient.

I'd like to mount a fan which extracts the hot air. Because I need to keep things cheap, preferably it would be some sort of computer(axial) fan (like this one: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/axial-fans/6688827/) but I am fairly worried about three things:

1. The cable might burn since the oven gets hot. It will be going around the outside.
2. The fan might melt, it does look like its from plastic?
3. It is usually rated 12V dc but I want to control it with a Rasp Pi model 3 b+, will I need an amplifier?

Comment: It's probably much better for the fan to blow cool air into the oven, if that is possible. Yes, computer fans are plastic and will probably melt if they get too hot. You will need at least a transistor between the fan and the RPi.

Comment: So "Lab oven" - what was its original purpose? high temperature ie lots of insulation? if so, then a different oven may be an idea...

Comment: @Solar Mike unfortunately not an option due to the budget. Indeed it is an idea though...

Comment: I agree with @Dampmaskin about blowing into the oven. If there is a second vent, blow into the first one. As far as I know it's better to use positive pressure to cool than negative pressure (push instead of suck). Downside is that this will only work if there is a second vent where the air can get pushed out.

Comment: @Dampmaskin will the cable last? Also, is there any sort of digital connection fans which are metal that I could use? Also, the melting point of plastic is 170 degrees. The vent is at the top and the fan will actually sit on top of the top of the oven, extracting it from the outside of the vent. Would it actually get hot enough to melt? It does say that the temp will be above 170 only between 30 and 90 seconds.

Comment: @Hein Wessels Well the thing is that the oven does have a fan already which is used to dissipate the heat... When I tried keeping that on after the heater was off, the oven still cooled very slowly even with the front door slightly open. And since the vent is on top and fan is blowing forward, it doesn't seem like the vent open is sufficient.

Comment: The melting point of plastic is 170 degrees - but at what temperature does the plastic go "soft" you may find this to be more of an issue.

Comment: @JimmyB that, surely is a question to ask the OP as it was their value given in their comment... Still my point was about it going soft - given the “normal” operating T of a computer fan...

Comment: Leaded 63/37 solder needs 150C to acivate its flux, and goes liquid at 183C. Kester EP256 for example, OEM datasheet here https://www.kester.com/products/product/ep256-solder-paste (Lead-free solder needs higher temps). Many parts have a do not exceed temperature of 205C.  You might want to review the fan you are using, perhaps find a metal fan.  Or do as others suggested, and blow air into the chamber - after the solder goes solid, you don't want to be blowing air into the champer before the solder has solidified, that will lead to cold solder joints.

Comment: IIRC lab ovens tend to have a fan to blow the air around inside, and that has nothing to do with dissipating the heat, more to do with even heating inside, like a home convection oven.

Comment: Consider also that it may not be unreasonably difficult to add a second hole on the bottom, you can put a hole in pretty much anything without too much trouble these days.  If you don't want it to be a heat loss/convection channel, you can add a complication to the airflow path on the bottom and an intake filter as well.